# Domain MX lookup shows My IP 0.0.0.0

Tags: networking, dns

My domain name is "beatzhost.com". I have setup my DNS server for mail server. I am using "http://www.mxtoolbox.com" to lookup DNS entries. My all entries are OK eventhough i am getting MX lookup result as 0.0.0.0. 
I want it to be my Domain IP. Operating System is Cent OS 5.

Comment: Your IP address for both the domain and the sub-domain are 175.100.168.123

Comment: [It's fairly foolish to blank out an IP address _that you are intending to publish, and indeed are publishing_ (as both d34dh0r53's and my tests confirm), _to the world_.](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/dont-obscure-your-dns-data.html)  Have a well-earned -1 for not even doing (and including in your question) the basic tests that I and d34dh0r53 both did, and then pointlessly obfuscating your data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks ok to me:

```
$dig -t mx beatzhost.com

; <<>> DiG 9.7.3-P3 <<>> -t mx beatzhost.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 36069
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 3, ADDITIONAL: 2

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;beatzhost.com.         IN  MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
beatzhost.com.      14400   IN  MX  0 smtp.beatzhost.com.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
beatzhost.com.      86400   IN  NS  ns2.beatzhost.com.
beatzhost.com.      86400   IN  NS  host.beatzhost.com.
beatzhost.com.      86400   IN  NS  ns1.beatzhost.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
smtp.beatzhost.com. 14400   IN  A   175.100.168.123
host.beatzhost.com. 14400   IN  A   175.100.168.123

;; Query time: 418 msec
;; SERVER: 10.6.23.4#53(10.6.23.4)
;; WHEN: Sun Dec 11 05:16:05 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 139
```